# MalformedInputException error from SparkStream App reading from Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am very new to Kafka and SparkStreaming. This Sparkstreaming consumer reads from Kafka (key is string and value is string) and when the data doesn't contain any escaped UTF8 string, it works fine. But when it does, it fails with the following error message:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(PipedRDD.scala:172)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is an example of those lines with escaped UTF8 string (note that it contains two slashes):

```
Los m\\xC3\\xA1s vendidos en ...
```

Initially I suspected Kafka streaming encoding configuration but changing it didn't help. In the end we found that the error happens when collect is executed against the data returned from Python UDF.

If more info is needed, please comment. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that our JVM encoding was set to ISO8859-1 in the data collection side (from Python UDF). So we ended up solving this by specifying utf-8 in calling pipe:

```
rdd.pipe(command, encoding = Codec.UTF8.name)
```